# PyQt: How to create a scrollable window

Tags: python, pyqt, scrollbar, qscrollarea

I think it should be much easier to create a scrollable window in PyQt. 
I have a list of labels that goes out of the window and I would like to scroll down to view them. At the moment the code does not give me an error, but the window just doesn't appear:

```
class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        lbl_arr = makeLabelArr()

        for i in range(1,8):
            qb = lbl_arr[i]
            # qb.setFixedWidth(300)
            layout.addWidget(qb)

        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidget(self)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll.setFixedHeight(400)

        layout.addWidget(scroll)

        self.setLayout(layout)


        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 600, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('SnP watchlist')

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    #print(QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry())

    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make the window itself a `QScrollArea`, like this:

```
class Window(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        for index in range(100):
            layout.addWidget(QLabel('Label %02d' % index))
        self.setWidget(widget)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)
```

Comment: I tried this without using a layout, but it's not working. Instead of inheriting from the "QMainWindow" class I created a "QWidget" object and passed that in every "Q" item I wanted to make. Example: https://pastebin.com/ZDKNXZPZ. Is this a wrong approach? I already created the window without a layout.

Comment: @Filip Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Can't do that. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

There is an example here: https://www.learnpyqt.com/tutorials/qscrollarea/

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QSlider, QLineEdit, QLabel, QPushButton, QScrollArea,QApplication,
                             QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()             # Scroll Area which contains the widgets, set as the centralWidget
        self.widget = QWidget()                 # Widget that contains the collection of Vertical Box
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()               # The Vertical Box that contains the Horizontal Boxes of  labels and buttons

        for i in range(1,50):
            object = QLabel("TextLabel: "+str(i))
            self.vbox.addWidget(object)

        self.widget.setLayout(self.vbox)

        #Scroll Area Properties
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)

        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 1000, 900)
        self.setWindowTitle('Scroll Area Demonstration')
        self.show()

        return

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `layout` after adding the `scroll bar` widget.

```
class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        lbl_arr = makeArrayOfLabelsHTML()

        for i in range(1,8):
            qb = lbl_arr[i]
            layout.addWidget(qb)

        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidget(self)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll.setFixedHeight(400)
        layout.addWidget(scroll)

        # set layout after adding scroll bar 
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 600, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('SnP watchlist')

        self.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':

        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        #print(QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry())

        ex = Example()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thanks for this, but still, the window does not show up even though I do not receive errors

Answer (score 0):

This illustrates one way to do things

```
import sys 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(600, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('One way to do scrolling')
        
        def add_stuff():
            self.add_stuff()
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(500, add_stuff)

    def add_stuff(self):
        self.resize(1200, 800)
        
        # comment out these blocks, starting with the bottom one
        
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        central_widget.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget))
        central_widget.setStyleSheet('border: 5px solid green;')
        
        scroll_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        central_widget.layout().addWidget(scroll_area)
        scroll_area.setStyleSheet('border: 5px solid blue;')
        
        main_panel = QtWidgets.QFrame(central_widget)
        main_panel.setStyleSheet('border: 5px solid red;')
        scroll_area.setWidget(main_panel)
        
        # the crucial line: without this, main_panel will just adapt
        # its size to its parent by default
        main_panel.setMinimumSize(600, 500)
        
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Run this and then make the window smaller using your mouse.

It's also important to be aware that some components, such as `QTableView` and `QTreeView`, implement scrolling components automatically.

The main thing to understand is that the scrolling happens because the child becomes too big for its parent (and its parent has set up scrolling). `setMinimumSize` is a very unsubtle way to illustrate this constraint: normally the child of a scroll-enabled parent will contain certain subcomponents which at some point will have a size below which they can't be compressed... the configured `layout` object of the child will also play a role in determining the minimum dimensions of the child.